# Ruby class variable initial value

Tags: ruby

In `PHP` I write:

```
Class Test{
  public $a=100;
}

$a=new Test();
echo $a->a; //prints 100
```

It prints `100`, but In ruby when I write:

```
class Test
  @a=100
  attr_accessor :a
end

a=Test.new
puts a.a #=> prints nil
```

`a` is nil and it prints `nil`. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mixing things a bit.

What you've defined with `@a = 100` is a *class instance variable*.

What you're going to have access to with `attr_accessor :a` is an *instance variable* `@a`.

Example of instance variable usage:

```
class A
  def initialize a
    @a = a
  end
  attr_accessor :a
end

instance = A.new(2)
#=> 2
instance.instance_variables
#=> [:@a]
instance.a
#=> 2
```

Example of class instance variable usage:

```
class A
  @a = 1
  class << self
    attr_accessor :a
  end
end

A.a
#=> nil
A.a = 2
#=> 2
A.a
#=> 2
instance = A.new
instance.class.a # access instance's class instance variable
#=> 2
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. So, can I say that `a` in inherited classes will be accessible with `100` value?

Comment: `cattr_accessor` is part of rails and inappropriate for this question (no `rails` tag)

Comment: @sokkyoku thx, edited

Comment: @emj, right. You can test it with `class B < A; end` and `B.a`

Comment: You should clarify, "Class instances DO NOT have access to their class' instance variables." If `@a` is a class instance variable with value "dog" and `@b` is an instance variable, `@b.class.a #=> "dog"` if `@a` has a read accessor, else `@b.class.instance_variable_get("@a") #=> "dog"`

Comment: @CarySwoveland I was not around my laptop since answered and was sure someone would stumble upon this sentence of mine :) Really there's nothing "inaccessible" in Ruby, but I'll update the answer once I am near laptop

Answer (score 2):

Instances variables belong to objects (aka instances), that's why they are called "instance variables" after all.

There are two objects here: `Test`, which is an instance of `Class`, and `a`, which is an instance of `Test`. Both are objects just like any other object. Both can have instance variables just like any other object.

Both have an instance variable called `@a`. `Foo`'s `@a` has been initialized to `100`. `a`'s `@a` hasn't been initialized at all, and unitialized instance variables evaluate to `nil`.

So, your problem is that you are confusing which instance you are looking at. Instance variables are always looked up in `self`, and inside a class definition body, `self` is the class being defined.

This may sound pedantic, but I find that understanding that Ruby is actually *much simpler* than people sometimes want you to believe, will ultimately help you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
class Test
  attr_accessor :a

  def initialize
    @a = 100
  end
end

a = Test.new
puts a.a
```

Comment: this is not an explanation/answer to the question "why?"

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is happening is that this line:

```
@a = 100
```

is assigning to an instance variable but not the one you think. It is being assigned to `Test.a`, (Test being an instance of `Class`) rather than to an instance variable `a` belonging to each instance of `Test`

In turn, this line:

```
attr_accessor :a
```

is declaring an accessor to an instance variable called `a` (accessible through any instance of `Test`)

Thus you should either have

```
class Test
    @a = 100
    class << self
        attr_accessor :a
    end
end
puts Test.a #=> will print 100
```

or

```
class Test
    def initialize
        @a = 100
    end
    attr_accessor :a
end
a = Test.new
puts a.a #=> will print 100
```

It depends if you just want a class constant or if you want an attribute with a default value on each instance. The latter is a direct translation of your PHP code.

Comment: It would be more precise (and ultimately more helpful) to say that that line *is* assigning an instance variable. After, all, it is an assignment (`=`), and it is an instance variable (`@`). It's just that the instance isn't the one the OP thinks it is. It *is* an instance variable, but for the *wrong* instance.

Comment: Good point, amended my answer